# Which is better in terms of performance, xmltable or xmlsequence in Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

Which is better in terms of performance: xmltable or xmlsequence in Oracle?

Comment: Why don't you try both on your `DEV` or `TEST` environment? That way you'll have the answer tailored specifically to your exact requirements and hardware/network etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think internally the execution plan is the same. Test the resource usage and execution plan using "set autotrace on"

Check out this article: 
http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/07/10/about-tablexmlsequence-and-xmltable/

Comment: I have used both approaches , using the xmltable is more clean and you can specify the data type of each column you are extracting , whereas in xmlsequence  you will have to extract and do  like "TO_DATE(EXTRACTVALUE (T2.column_value, 'ROW/LAST_UPDATING_DATE'),'DD-MON-YYYY') LAST_UPDATING_DATE".I have already checked the link http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/07/10/about-tablexmlsequence-and-xmltable/, i am looking for more factual inputs

Comment: One more difference is that xmlsequence is deprecated in oracle 11g r2

Comment: There you are! Fact: don't use xmlsequence !

Answer (score 0):

With Respect to the question, Please find some Factual points

1. Feature is Deprecated in 12c+, Prefer to Use XMLTable
2. Performance wise XMLTABLE Is Good, if you have 2 or more PATH Expressions to be retrieved,
3. Parsing for each Column takes time, instead you can create view using XML TABLE and XMLTYPE
   [Refer this Link xmlTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690868/how-to-use-xmltable-in-oracle)
4. Additional Reference -
   [https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/03/15/oracle-database-xmltable-vs-extractvalue-performance/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690868/how-to-use-xmltable-in-oracle)