# how to get boolean value of XML data in oracle procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, parsing, soap, oracle11g

I am calling a SOAP webService from oracle which is returning xml response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <boolean xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods">
     false
  </boolean>
```

I need to catch the boolean value so I found this [how to use xmltable in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690868/how-to-use-xmltable-in-oracle) but I don't how to do it with my simple boolean response, any hints?

Comment: Huh?  You want a SQL query to extract the value of the element names <boolean>?

Comment: Yes @OldProgrammer, webservice reponse is a boolean tag. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH test_data AS
  (SELECT xmltype('<boolean xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods">false</boolean>') data
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT extractValue(data,'/boolean','xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods"')
FROM test_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to modify the XML string to remove the namespace, you can incorporate that into your XML query. OldProgrammer already showed how to do that with the deprecated `extractValue()` function, but you can do the same thing with the XMLTable you asked about:

```
FUNCTION XMLTEST (P_XML VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    V_FLAG VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT P.boolean
    INTO   V_FLAG
    FROM   xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods'),
           '/boolean' passing xmltype(P_XML) 
           columns boolean VARCHAR2(30) PATH '.') P;

    RETURN V_FLAG;
END XMLTEST;
```

Or - as you're expected a single node, and will get an error from the XMLTable version if there are multiples anyway - an XMLQuery:

```
    SELECT XMLQuery(
        'declare default element namespace "http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods"; (: :)
        /boolean/text()'
        passing xmltype(P_XML)
        returning content).getStringVal()
    INTO   V_FLAG
    FROM   dual;
```

[Read more about XMLTable and XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm), and how they handle namespaces.

It's also possible to wildcard the XPath:

```
    SELECT XMLQuery('/*:boolean/text()'
        passing xmltype(P_XML)
        returning content).getStringVal()
    INTO   V_FLAG
    FROM   dual;
```

With your formatted XML string the extracted value is more than just the string `'false'` - it has leading and trailing spaces and newline characters, which you could then strip out if necessary. If your real XML has `<boolean>false</boolean>` with no extra whitespace then that isn't necessary, of course, and your `v_flag` only needs to be five characters long.

You don't need to do this in PL/SQL, but that seems to be a requirement you are imposing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was with xmlns ="..." should remove it to get the answer

```
FUNCTION XMLTEST (P_XML VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
                     V_FLAG VARCHAR2(4000);
                     V_XML1 VARCHAR2(4000);
                     V_XML2 VARCHAR2(4000);  
                     V_XML VARCHAR2(4000);               
                BEGIN  
                    V_XML1 := SUBSTR(P_XML,0,INSTR(P_XML,'xmlns')-1)||'>';
                    V_XML2 := SUBSTR(P_XML,INSTR(P_XML,'/Methods">')+10);
                    V_XML  := V_XML1||V_XML2;

                    SELECT P.boolean
                    INTO   V_FLAG
                    FROM   xmltable('/boolean' passing xmltype(V_XML) 
                                columns boolean VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'text()') P;

                    RETURN V_FLAG;           

                END XMLTEST;
```